# How to display build status badge from .onion domain on GitHub?

Tags: github, tor, badge, readme

Suppose one hosts its GitLab Server and Runners on a `.onion` address. How could one modify a regular build status badge:

[image: Build Status]

To a .onion status badge and display it on GitHub? E.g:

```
<a href="http://somelonggitlabserverdomain.onion/danielduarte/flowed"><img src="http://somelonggitlabserverdomain.onion/danielduarte/flowed.svg?branch=main" alt="Build Status"></a>
```

Comment: You have the tag `github` here.  Are you asking about rendering the status badge on GitHub, on this self-hosted GitLab instance, or elsewhere (and if so, where)?  The answer depends on where you want to display it.

Comment: Thank you for your question, I included that the status badge is intended to be rendered on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is going to be practically impossible to do, unless you have some sort of website which can proxy requests to `.onion` domains.  That's because all third-party images on GitHub go through a proxy called Camo, and Camo can't resolve `.onion` domains because GitHub doesn't run Tor.

Avoiding this proxy isn't possible for security and tracking reasons, and even if you could bypass it, the Content-Security-Policy header on GitHub would tell your browser not to render it.

So the only way to make this work would be to find some domain that could proxy this image for you to something accessible in the normal DNS.

Comment: Thank you for providing this nuanced clarity. Even though dependencies on external are being circumvented in the XY-problem by hosting the GitLab server over tor, I just thought perhaps it is possible to host a GitHub website that gets those build statuses from `.onion` domains. In that case, the external dependency is the domain registrar and GitHub. I thought perhaps GitHub provides more flexibility on a hosted website than they do on their own Readme's.